# How to enable intellisense/ JSDoc info on hover in WebStorm?

Tags: webstorm, intellisense, jsdoc

Behaviour like in **Visual Studio** is what I would like. Like this:

[image]

or like this:

[image]

**Currently**, I get **nothing on hover** and only the **basic type info whilst typing**:

[image]

Is this possible and if so, how?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try enabling **Show quick documentation on mouse move** in `Settings | Editor | General` to show docs on mouse hover. Note that normally documentation popup is available on `Ctrl+Q` (`View | Quick documentation`)